# What does it mean for something to "compose well"?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, clojure, composition

Many a times, I've come across statements of the form
X does/doesn't compose well.

I can remember few instances that I've read recently :

- Macros don't compose well (context: clojure)
- Locks don't compose well (context: clojure)
- Imperative programming doesn't compose well... etc.

I want to understand the implications of composability in terms of designing/reading/writing code ? Examples would be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does composability mean in context of functional programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887013/what-does-composability-mean-in-context-of-functional-programming)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Composing" functions basically just means sticking two or more functions together to make a big function that combines their functionality in a useful way. Essentially, you define a sequence of functions and pipe the results of each one into the next, finally giving the result of the whole process. Clojure provides the `comp` function to do this for you, you could do it by hand too.

Functions that you can chain with other functions in creative ways are more useful in general than functions that you can only call in certain conditions. For example, if we didn't have the `last` function and only had the traditional Lisp list functions, we could easily define `last` as `(def last (comp first reverse))`. Look at that — we didn't even need to `defn` or mention any arguments, because we're just piping the result of one function into another. This would not work if, for example, `reverse` took the imperative route of modifying the sequence in-place. Macros are problematic as well because you can't pass them to functions like `comp` or `apply`.

Comment: An example of macros not composing well.  Say we wanted to do something like this.  (reduce and [true true false true]).  Unfortunately because and is a macro we can't pass it to reduce.

Comment: "if `reverse` took the imperative route of modifying the sequence in-place". Is this not more a question of API? What if it `reverse` returns the mutated sequence? I guess you would need to say to users that it will reverse the list. That's an impratical API but is it uncomposable?

Answer (score 4):

Composition in programming means assembling bigger pieces out of smaller ones.

- Composition of unary functions creates a more complicated unary function by chaining simpler ones.
- Composition of control flow constructs places control flow constructs inside other control flow constructs.
- Composition of data structures combines multiple simpler data structures into a more complicated one.

Ideally, a composed unit works like a basic unit and you as a programmer do not need to be aware of the difference.  If things fall short of the ideal, if something doesn't compose well, your composed program may not have the (intended) combined behavior of its individual pieces.

Suppose I have some simple C code.

```
void run_with_resource(void) {
  Resource *r = create_resource();
  do_some_work(r);
  destroy_resource(r);
}
```

C facilitates compositional reasoning about control flow at the level of functions.  I don't have to care about what actually happens inside do_some_work(); I know just by looking at this small function that every time a resource is created on line 2 with create_resource(), it will eventually be destroyed on line 4 by destroy_resource().

Well, not quite.  What if create_resource() acquires a lock and destroy_resource() frees it?  Then I have to worry about whether do_some_work acquires the same lock, which would prevent the function from finishing.  What if do_some_work() calls longjmp(), and skips the end of my function entirely?  Until I know what goes on in do_some_work(), I won't be able to predict the control flow of my function.  We no longer have compositionality: we can no longer decompose the program into parts, reason about the parts independently, and carry our conclusions back to the whole program.  This makes designing and debugging much harder and it's why people care whether something composes well.

Answer (score 2):

Composition (in the context you describe at a functional level) is typically the ability to feed one function into another cleanly and without intermediate processing.  Such an example of composition is in std::cout in C++:

cout << each << item << links << on;

That is a simple example of composition which doesn't really "look" like composition.

Another example with a form more visibly compositional:

foo(bar(baz()));

[Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29)

Composition is useful for readability and compactness, however chaining large collections of interlocking functions which can potentially return error codes or junk data can be hazardous (this is why it is best to minimize error code or null return values.)

Provided your functions use exceptions, or alternatively return [null objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) you can minimize the requirement for branching (if) on errors and maximize the compositional potential of your code at no extra risk.

---

Object [composition (vs inheritance)](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html) is a separate issue (and not what you are asking, but it shares the name).  It is one of containment to derive object hierarchy as opposed to direct inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

"Bang for the Buck" - composing well implies a high ratio of expressiveness per rule-of-composition. Each macro introduces its own rules of composition. Each custom data structure does the same. Functions,  especially those using general data structures have far fewer rules.

Assignment and other side effects, especially wrt concurrency have even more rules.

Answer (score 2):

Think about when you write functions or methods.  You create a group of functionality to do a specific task.  When working in an Object Oriented language you cluster your behavior around the actions you think a distinct entity in the system will perform.  Functional programs break away from this by encouraging authors to group functionality according to an abstraction.  For example, the Clojure Ring library comprises a group of abstractions that cover routing in web applications.

Ring is composable where functions that describe paths in the system (routes) can be grouped into higher order functions (middlewhere).  In fact, Clojure is so dynamic that it is possible (and you are encouraged) to come up with patterns of routes that can be dynamically created at runtime.  This is the essence of composablilty, instead of coming up with patterns that solve a certain problem you focus on patterns that generate solutions to a certain class of problem.  Builders and code generators are just two of the common patterns used in functional programming.  Function programming is the art of patterns that generate other patterns (and so on and so on).

The idea is to solve a problem at its most basic level then come up with patterns or groups of the lowest level functions that solve the problem.  Once you start to see patterns in the lowest level you've discovered composition.  As folks discover second order patterns in groups of functions they may start to see a third level.  And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of clojure, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493047/what-is-the-correct-term-for-the-following-functional-programming-pattern/3497939#3497939) addresses certain aspects of composability.  In general, it seems to emerge when units of the system do one thing well, do not require other units to understand its internals, eschew side-effects, and accept and return the system's pervasive data structures.  All of the above can be seen in M2tM's C++ example.

Answer (score 1):

**composability**, applied to functions, means that the functions are smaller and well-defined, thus easy to integrate into other functions (i have seen this idea in the book "the joy of clojure")

the concept can apply to other things that are supposed be composed into something else.

***the purpose*** of composability is reuse. for example, a function well-build (composable) is easier to reuse

*macros* aren't that well-composable because you can't pass them as parameters

*lock* are crap because you can't really give them names (define them well) or reuse them. you just do them inplace

*imperative languages* aren't that composable because (some of them, at least) don't have *closures*. if you want functionality passed as parameter, you're screwed. you have to build an object and pass that; **disclaimer** here: this last idea i'm not entirely convinced is true, therefore research more before taking it for granted

another idea on *imperative languages* is that they don't compose well because they imply **state** (from [wikipedia knowledgebase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms) :) "Imperative programming - describes computation in terms of statements that change a program state").

**state** does not compose well because although you have given a specific "something" in input, that "something" generates an output according to it's state. different internal state, different behaviour. and thus you can say good-bye to what you where expecting to happen.

with state, you depend to much on knowing what the current state of an object is... if you want to predict it's behavior. more stuff to keep in the back of your mind, less composable (remember *well-defined* ? or "**small** and simple", as in "easy to use" ?)

*ps: thinking of learning clojure, huh ? investigating... ? good for you ! :P*